# MediaMuxer Continuous Capture

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, mediamuxer

I am trying the example [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika). I am interested in the `ContinuousCapture` example that records video to the file system and draw it into the screen at the same time. The problem I have is record video to the file system seems to be very slow. There are lots of dropped frame and the frame per second is only 7-10fps.

Inside the main `drawFrame()` method,

```
private void drawFrame() {
    //Log.d(TAG, "drawFrame");
    if (mEglCore == null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Skipping drawFrame after shutdown");
        return;
    }

    // Latch the next frame from the camera.
    mDisplaySurface.makeCurrent();
    mCameraTexture.updateTexImage();
    mCameraTexture.getTransformMatrix(mTmpMatrix);

    // Fill the SurfaceView with it.
    SurfaceView sv = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.continuousCapture_surfaceView);
    int viewWidth = sv.getWidth();
    int viewHeight = sv.getHeight();
    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, viewWidth, viewHeight);
    mFullFrameBlit.drawFrame(mTextureId, mTmpMatrix);
    drawExtra(mFrameNum, viewWidth, viewHeight);
    mDisplaySurface.swapBuffers();

    // Send it to the video encoder.
    if (!mFileSaveInProgress) {
        mEncoderSurface.makeCurrent();
        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, VIDEO_WIDTH, VIDEO_HEIGHT);
        Log.d(TAG, "start drawing video");
        mFullFrameBlit.drawFrame(mTextureId, mTmpMatrix);
        Log.d(TAG, "finish drawing video");
        drawExtra(mFrameNum, VIDEO_WIDTH, VIDEO_HEIGHT);
        mCircEncoder.frameAvailableSoon();
        mEncoderSurface.setPresentationTime(mCameraTexture.getTimestamp());
        mEncoderSurface.swapBuffers();
    }

    mFrameNum++;
}
```

The main performance bottleneck seems to be

```
    Log.d(TAG, "start drawing video");
    mFullFrameBlit.drawFrame(mTextureId, mTmpMatrix);
    Log.d(TAG, "finish drawing video");
```

with the time between the 2 logs are 130ms. The Android MediaRecorder could do the job at 30fps, high quality video. I tried to disable the display part but it makes no difference

Comment: What device are you experimenting with? From my experience FPS differs depending on device and video resolution. We tried to make such usage scenarios profiling on devices that give low FPS, but did not find a way to increase fps to 30 fps on 720p yet

Comment: What do you mean by "tried to disable the display part but it makes no difference"?  Do you see performance issues in the other Grafika activities on this device (e.g. "Continuous capture" or "Texture from camera")?

Comment: In the Continuous Capture, the activity draws into the screen and write into the file at the same time. So, I tried to disable the display part to see if there is any performance improvement.

I think it has more to do with the writing video

Comment: Have seen slow encoding performance in some 4.3 devices like GS3, when use mediarecorder, or when using software memory to MediaCodec, device does use hardware accelerated encoding, but if to use opengl surfaces, then it falls into software encoding, I've seen that by looking a system wide profiler output, and it was obvious that all CPU cores occupied by AVCEncBufPrc routine, however internet doesn't know that callback, and it lasts about 120-130ms per each frame. You can try same analysis on your system, using [link](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/systrace.html)

Comment: I am encoding on Galaxy S3, so it may be the same issue. MediaRecorder works fine in this device, though

Comment: MediaRecorder works on lower then MediaCodec and connected stuff level. In other words is has more optimal and correct way to make processing without some unexpected software encodings or so